# Unknown Database Content

Tags: mongodb

I was given the data files to MongoDB without being told much of what was in the content. Is there a way to probe the contents of the database to identify commonalities within the database.

Comment: Have you imported into a temporary db to look around? or you mean static analysis of the files you've received?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different [`mongo` shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell) helpers that will give you an idea of the general structure of collections (eg. field/data types and their frequency of usage in a collection):

- [schema.js](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mongodb-schema/)
- [variety](https://github.com/variety/variety)

To get a better idea of the actual content, you could try one of the [Admin UIs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs).